# \tikzexternalize doesn't work with lua code

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

The following code from the pgf manual compiles fine with `lualatex --shell-escape`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
A simple image is \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);.
\end{document}
```

But, if I write some luacode (for example `$\pi = \directlua{tex.sprint(math.pi)}$`) I have the following error message :

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -inter
action=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test}\input{
test}"' ========
runsystem(pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0
" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test}\input{test}")...executed.
./test.tex:7: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-err
or -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{tes
t}\input{test}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'test-figure0' (expecte
d one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system cal
ls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 
'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error me
ssages can be found in 'test-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typ
eset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 ...ple image is \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);
```

The question is: what's wrong? And subsidiarily, why is pdflatex invoked?

N.B. The compilation with lua code fails only if I deleted the aux files before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change the program PGF/TikZ calls to generate the external graphics with the key `/tikz/external/system call` (see the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/get/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), page 345). The default value is

```
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

Replacing `pdflatex` with `lualatex` should solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
A simple image is \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);.
$\pi = \directlua{tex.sprint(math.pi)}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This just saved my day. The problem still persists in pgfplots 1.7. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't working for me, and `lualatex --help` shows that it uses double-hyphen for options, but even fixing that doesn't help.  Any extra troubleshooting steps needed?  I have TexWorks and MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Ahh, spaces in the filename of the master document are particularly problematic for lualatex (moreso than pdflatex, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what is wrong is exactly that `pdflatex` is called.  It does not understand `\directlua`, and therefore cannot produce your external graphics.

The reason that `pdflatex` is calls seems to be that it is hardcoded in the `/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzexternalshared.code.tex` file.  Try to edit that file, and replace each call to `pdflatex` by `lualatex`.  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Seems to be best to [write a bug report for PGF/TikZ](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=142562&atid=752792) then.