# lualatex texlive 2016 broken with tikzexternalize

Tags: luatex, texlive, tikz-external

The following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
A simple image is \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);.
$\pi = \directlua{tex.sprint(math.pi)}$
\end{document}
```

Taken from [\tikzexternalize doesn't work with lua code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12429/tikzexternalize-doesnt-work-with-lua-code) seems to be broken with texlive 2016 (at least on my computer, Ubuntu 16, vanilla texlive). On texlive 2015 it works just fine.

The failure is in that the external pdf file is not written. Buried in the log:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{t
est}\input{test}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'test-figure0' (expec
ted one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system c
alls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also name
d 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error 
messages can be found in 'test-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to t
ypeset the picture.
```

What's changed? Any workaround?

Comment: See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313284/tex-live-2016-minted-doesnt-work-with-lualatex

Comment: Yep, that solve the issue. Feel free to add it as an answer (or mark the question as duplicate)